# Is there a simple way of showing that the directional derivative is the dot product of grad(f) with the directional vector u?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I am reading a sort of technical proof but I would like to prove it myself in a cleaner and shorter way.

So, I want to show

$$D_uf = \nabla f. u$$

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

EDIT:  I think I will try to work backwards, using matrix multiplication, since grad(f) can be viewed as a 1x2 matrix.

Comment: `\nabla` for $\nabla$

Comment: Thanks so much @Henry -- I just edited my question to include this notation  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is your definition of the gradient? In many cases $\nabla f$ is *defined* to be the vector with $\langle\nabla f, u\rangle = D_uf$. (It is then shown that this vector is well-defined, which follows immediately from linearity of $D$ with respect to $u$.)

The above definition has the great advantage of being coordinate-independent: it will work on any manifold with any metric, on functionals acting on function spaces (when suitably interpreted in terms of variations), etc. But perhaps you're in Euclidean space and have defined $\nabla f= \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, \ldots\right)$. You can show that this is equivalent to the definition above by taking $u$ to be the Cartesian basis vectors $e_i$ and then applying linearity of the directional derivative.

Comment: Hi @user7530, I am afraid that I cannot assume and use the linearity of the directional derivative.  In the proof that I am reading, the linearity is proved along the way, before proving the equation...

Comment: Hi @user7530 -- so I've worked out all of the details to show the linearity of the directional derivative, and then the application of linearity quickly proves the equation, as you had mentioned.  Thanks so much for your help.  :-)

Comment: Actually, I have one silly follow-up question @user7530: the directional vector is never the zero vector, right?  Perhaps partly to avoid trivialities, and also perhaps it wouldn't make sense because the zero vector doesn't have a direction -- it only has a magnitude, which is zero.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: You can take the directional derivative in the zero vector direction; you just get zero, of course.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks again @user7530 :-)

Answer (score 4):

For given point $p$ and direction $u$, $$f(x_p+tu_x,y_p+tu_y,z_p+tu_z)=\phi(t)$$ is a function of $t$ that indicates how $f$ evolves along the straight line through $p$ in the direction $u$.

Then by the chain rule,

$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}u_x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}u_y+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}u_z=\nabla f\cdot u.$$

Comment: Hi @YvesDaoust -- in your second equality, is the derivative of phi, with respect to t, exactly the directional derivative of f, evaluated at point p, in the direction of u?  If so, can you elaborate just a bit more on why it is?  Thanks,

Comment: This is the sort of proof that I was hoping to come up with, although the more technical proof that proves and then applies linearity of the directional derivative was not as bad as I thought it would be.  But your $\phi ' (t) $ is a little tricky for me to understand.  I'm looking at the limit definition of the directional derivative and don't really understand how to go from that, namely differentiating with respect to x, y, or some other direction, to a derivative with respect to time...

Comment: @LebronJames: there is no time here, but traversed length in the given direction.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Suppose $f$ is differentiable at a point $a$. If $h > 0$, if $u$ is unit, and if $x := a + hu$ lies in some suitable open ball around $a$, then
$$
\frac{|f(x) - f(a) - \nabla f(a)(x-a)|}{|hu|} = \frac{|f(a+hu) - f(a) - \nabla f(a)(hu)|}{h}\\ = \big| \frac{f(a+hu) - f(a)}{h} - \nabla f(a)u \big| \to 0
$$
as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Hi @GudsonChou, how did you get the numerator on the left-most side of your string of equalities?  It looks like a linearization of f or something coming from the multivariable Taylor expansion.  Also, how do we know the last difference in your equality converges to zero?  Thanks,

Comment: No problem. That is why I call it a hint :) Think about the relation between the Jacobian matrix of $f$ and the derivative of $f$.

Comment: Hi @GudsonChou, in your last term (that you show goes to zero), it is just the directional derivative - grad(f)*u.  But, this is what we are trying to show --  you seem to have just set the difference equal to zero.  Unless I am missing something obvious.  Thanks,

Comment: Because we are assuming that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Hi @GudsonChou, I worked out the (sort of) tedious details of the proof that first proves linearity of the directional derivative, and then applied the linearity to prove the equation.  Thanks for your time.  :-)